# Importing csv file to nested resource models (has_many :through etc.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I hope that someone can help me with importing csv file into nested resource model.
I have a couple of models (Rails 4.0, Ruby 2.0):

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :level_type
      has_many :project_levels
  has_many :projects, through: :project_levels
end

class LevelType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :levels
end

class ProjectLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :level
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :project_levels
  has_many :levels, through: :project_levels 
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

And what I do similar to this in a rake task:

```
company.projects.create(company_name: row[3])

level_type.levels.create(position: row[4])
```

My problems is how to create levels from companies? Is this the right thing to do?

```
company.projects.levels.create(company_name: row[3])
```

What is confusing me is that I have 2 sides to get to the levels and the same information I have to put into it (company_name: row[3]) and I am not sure how to deal with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yes but the problem was that I wanted the rake task to handle everything without a controller. Thanks, I managed to solve it later.

Comment: @user1993565 : Can you post your solution?